# Convert Vector3 to float in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class GetPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 dragStartPosition;
    float dragStartDistance;
    float[] Xfloat;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        dragStartPosition = transform.position;
        dragStartDistance = (Camera.main.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
            Vector3 worldDragTo = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, dragStartDistance));
            transform.position = new Vector3(worldDragTo.x, dragStartPosition.y, dragStartPosition.z);
            new Vector3(worldDragTo.x, dragStartPosition.y, dragStartPosition.z);
            float Newpos = ;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
    }

}
```

I have this code in unity and I would like to convert my new Vector3 (only position x) to a float, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
float Newpos = worldDragTo.x;
```

as the components of a Vector3 are already floats.

If they were another floating point type you'd need to cast as you are losing precision with your conversion so there's no implicit cast from double or decimal down to float.

Though you are creating a vector without assigning it to a variable so you're throwing it away.

```
new Vector3(worldDragTo.x, dragStartPosition.y, dragStartPosition.z);
```